# How can Nucleus get the ID list?

Tags: operating-system, embedded

These days, I start learning the Nucleus Plus OS. After build the OS and download the image into the board, the OS cannot run successfully. And I find the error occurs on the function CMEM_Index(); I have read the code, but I cannot find out the reason. And I even don't know how the system get the ID lists such as combo_mem_id_list.
Now here is the code for CMEM_Index().
Is there anyone know something about Nucleus Plus? Or who can tell me how can the system get the nor flash ID list? Plz.

```
#if defined(__DUAL_SERIAL_FLASH_SUPPORT__)
kal_int32 CMEM_Index(const kal_uint16 CS)
#else //ADMUX or Nand or SF without Dual SF enable
kal_int32 CMEM_Index()
#endif
{
    kal_int32 i, j;
    CMEMFlashID id;
    const CMEMEntryID *id_list=NULL;

#if !defined(__DUAL_SERIAL_FLASH_SUPPORT__)
    if (cmem_index>=0) return cmem_index;
#endif

// Read Flash ID
#if defined(_NAND_FLASH_BOOTING_)
    #if defined(__UBL__)
    return CMEM_INVALID_INDEX;
    #else
    if(DAL_is_initialized == 0)
    {
        DAL_init(); // Call DAL init to ensure FlashID alreay there.
    }
    MTD_ReadID(8, id.NAND);
    #endif
#elif defined(__DUAL_SERIAL_FLASH_SUPPORT__)
  #if defined(__UBL__)
    //begin from MT6255, remapping is done before NOR_ReadID
    if(CS !=2) //Skip Read ID for dummy SF2
    {
        if(EMI_QueryIsRemapped())
            NOR_ReadID(CS,(void*)0x10000000, id.NOR);
        else
            NOR_ReadID(CS, (void*)0, id.NOR);
    }
  #else
    if(CS !=2)//Skip Read ID for dummy SF2
        NOR_ReadID(CS, (void *)(INT_RetrieveFlashBaseAddr() + NOR_FLASH_BASE_ADDRESS), id.NOR);
  #endif
#else //ADMUX and SF without Dual SF enable
  #if defined(__UBL__)
    //begin from MT6255, remapping is done before NOR_ReadID
        if(EMI_QueryIsRemapped())
            NOR_ReadID(0,(void*)0x10000000, id.NOR);
        else
            NOR_ReadID(0, (void*)0, id.NOR);
  #else
        NOR_ReadID(0, (void *)(INT_RetrieveFlashBaseAddr() + NOR_FLASH_BASE_ADDRESS), id.NOR);
  #endif
#endif //defined(_NAND_FLASH_BOOTING_)

#ifdef   __SV5_ENABLED__
    id_list=combo_mem_id_list.m_data.List;
#else
    id_list=combo_mem_id_list.List;
#endif

    // seach CMEM list for specific Flash ID
    for (i=0; i<COMBO_MEM_DEVICE_COUNT; i++)    {
        // Check 1: Compare ID
        for (j=0; j<id_list[i].IDLength; j++) {
            #if defined(_NAND_FLASH_BOOTING_)
            if (id_list[i].ID[j]!=id.NAND[j]) break;
            #else // __SERIAL_FLASH__ || NOR FLASH
            if (id_list[i].ID[j]!=id.NOR[j]) break;
            #endif
        }
        // Check 2: Compare RegionInfo
        if (j==id_list[i].IDLength)   {
            // TBD: Compare RegionInfo
            cmem_index=i;
            break;  // entry found, break the loop
        }
    }
#if defined(__DUAL_SERIAL_FLASH_SUPPORT__)
    /*Get Dummy SF entry ID*/
    if(CS==2)
    {
        // seach CMEM list for specific Flash ID
        for (i=0; i<COMBO_MEM_DEVICE_COUNT; i++)    {
            // Check 1: Compare ID
            for (j=0; j<id_list[i].IDLength; j++) {
                if(j==0)
                    if (id_list[i].ID[j]!= 0x00) break;
                if(j==1)
                    if (id_list[i].ID[j]!= 0x34) break;
                if(j==2)
                    if (id_list[i].ID[j]!= 0x56) break;
            }

            if (j==id_list[i].IDLength)   
            {
                // TBD: Compare RegionInfo
                cmem_index=i;
                break;  // entry found, break the loop
            }
        }
    }
#endif

    return cmem_index;
}
```